# PyQt returning empty string from a class?

Tags: python, pyqt

The code is along the lines of this:

```
class Solver(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        blabla

    def solver(self):
        return qlineedit1.text()

class access(QMainWindow):
    prda = Solver().solver()
    print prda
```

The problem is that prda is an empty string. If i put "print qlineedit1.text()" in the Solver class, the text is displayed as it should be. However, when "transferred" to a different class, the string is empty. The weirdest part that it is there - if I do type(prda), I get QString type output.

So, how would I get prda to assume the value of qlineedit1.text() ? I was thinking of writing the text to file in Solver class, and then reading it from access class, but there has to be another solution. By the way, the Solver class and the access class are two dialogs.

Help?

Comment: I can not replicate this. Is there maybe something else going on in the omitted parts?

Comment: It may be. What could cause a QString to be there, but be empty? :/

Comment: Can't say without seeing more of the code.

Comment: Best solution is to cut `QString` out so it'll give a `unicode` object instead: use PySide, or do what http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/incompatible_apis.html shows you. That and similar simplify so many things...

Comment: I hope, also, that your `Solver.__init__` calls `super(Solver, self).__init__(parent)`?

Comment: Chris, yes the Solver class does call super(Solver, self).__init__(parent). Also, I ended up solving the problem. The problem was that the dialog (Solver()) was closed before it managed to pass the variable to the access() class, i.e. access() was trying to access a variable that has been garbage-collected by PyQt

Comment: OK, that's interesting. That was my first "wild" guess. That's why I tried to replicate it, but it didn't happen here. Anyway, glad you could work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since next code works as expected, all i can think out without seeing more of your code is that your `qlineedit1` is empty.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Solver(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        print "in Solver init"

    def solver(self):
        return "in solver() method"

class access(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    prda = Solver()
    print prda.solver()
    #this will work too:
    #prda = Solver().solver()
    #print prda

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    acc=access()
    acc.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```